# Collision detection: Ball landing on Platform

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to make a game and with platforms randomly generating moving to the top of the screen. The ball is landing on the platforms being generated.

```
for i in range (12):
    platforms.append([random.randint(1,w), random.randint(1,h), random.randint(speed,-1)])

while True:  
    screen.fill(black)

    # Platforms
    for  i in range (len(platforms)):
        pygame.draw.rect (screen,white,(platforms[i][0],platforms[i][1],rectW,rectH))
        platforms[i][1] = platforms [i][1] + platforms [i][2]
        if (platforms [i][1] < 0):
            platforms [i][1] = h-death
            platforms [i][0] = random.randint(1,w)
    # Collision Detection
    print (x1,y1,platforms[i][1])
    for i in range (len(platforms)):
        if x1 >= platforms[i][0] and x1 <= platforms[i][0] + rectW:
            print ('hello')
            if y1 == platforms[i][0]:
                print ("HIT")
```

What do I need to change to make the y1 move up with the platform or make "HIT" print

Comment: BTW: pygame has `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size and it has `player_rect.colliderect(platform_rect)`.

Comment: to check collision with platform you have to also compare `y` - but use `<=` instead of `==` and if there is collision then always set `player.bottom = platform.top` - but you would have to use [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to have access to `rect.bottom` and `rect.top` . When platform will move up then `player.bottom = platform.top` will move up player too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Shortly: you should use `<=` instead of `==` and `[1]` instead of `[0]`

```
if y1 <= platforms[i][1]: 
   print ("HIT")
   y1 = platforms[i][1] # move up with platform
```

---

First you should use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size. It has property `x` `y` `width`, `height` but also useful `bottom`, `top`, `center`, etc.

It has also method to check collision between two `Rect()`

```
player_rect.colliderect(platform_rect)
```

When you get collision between player and platform then you have to change player's `bottom`  using platform's `top`

```
    if player_rect.colliderect(platform_rect):
        player_rect.bottom = platform_rect.top
```

and it will move player with platform.

---

Minimal working code: red platform moves up and automatically player moves up too.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25 # for more than 220 it has no time to update screen

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

player_rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,50,50)
player_color = (0,255,0)
player_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
player_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom-25

platform_rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,200,25)
platform_color = (255,0,0)
platform_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
platform_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    platform_rect.y -= 1

    if player_rect.colliderect(platform_rect):
        player_rect.bottom = platform_rect.top

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, platform_color, platform_rect)    

    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** Example with platform moving down. It uses `player_gravity` to keep player on platform when platform moves down.

If `player_gravity` is the same as `plaftorm_speed` then player stays on platform - but it `player_gravity` is smaller than `plaftorm_speed` then player falls slower then platform (like with parachute)

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25 # for more than 220 it has no time to update screen

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

player_rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,50,50)
player_color = (0,255,0)
player_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
player_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom-25
player_gravity = 3 # try 5

platform_rect = pygame.Rect(0,0,200,25)
platform_color = (255,0,0)
platform_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
platform_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom
platform_direction = 'top'
platform_speed = 5

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    if platform_direction == 'top':
        platform_rect.y -= platform_speed
        if platform_rect.top <= 100:
            platform_direction = 'bottom'
    else:
        platform_rect.y += platform_speed
        if platform_rect.bottom >= 600:
            platform_direction = 'top'

    player_rect.y += player_gravity 

    if player_rect.colliderect(platform_rect):
        player_rect.bottom = platform_rect.top

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player_rect)    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, platform_color, platform_rect)    

    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: this will only work if I hard code the rectangles I won't be able to control the rectangles and I need to be able to move them left and right

Comment: it is only **minimal** example which shows how to move player when platform is moving. Now you have to use it with your list of platforms - ie `platforms[i][0]`. I don't have your full code so don't expect full solution for your code. Besides you don't use `pygame.Rect()`.

Comment: Shortly: you need `<=` and `[1]` instead of `[0]` in `if y1 <= platforms[i][1]: y1 = platforms[i][0]`. I add it now in answer.